# How to apply the styles described in the string from the function in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I use a package that provides me a calendar widget. (*rc-calendar*)

I do not have access to dates, except that each cell in the table has a title (ex: **12. Febrary 2019**)

On certain days I need to customize the styles.
Therefore, I came to this decision

```
.rc-calendar-tbody td [title * = "2019"]> div: after {
    content: "·";
    display: none;
    color: $ color-main-yellow;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    top: 10px;
    left: calc (50% + -5px);
}
```

Great, now it remains to find out what specific days you need to customize.

I have access to all calendar days and my unix array

And that's what I came to

```
showDaysWithEvent = (date) => {
   let day = moment (date) .format ('D');
   let month = moment (date) .format ('MMMM');
   let dot = `.rc-calendar-tbody td [title * ="${day}. ${month} "]> div: after {display: block}`;

   if (moment (date) .unix () === 1548608654) {
      console.log (dot);
   }
};
```

How do I apply these styles so that they instantly appear on the calendar?

What to do with - **let dot**?

Comment: react-calendar provides custom styling, but you need import it differently: `import Calendar from 'react-calendar/dist/entry.nostyle';`

Comment: Iam sorry - rc-calendar instead